# how to get the links between two nodes using R or python

Tags: python, r, machine-learning

I am new to R and I need code for the following requirement:

There are src and trg records like 1 matched with 2, 2-3,3-4.

Now when I ask the system to provide link between 1 and 4 it should give me o/p as 1-2-3-4.

When I ask the system to give link between 2 and 4 it should give 2-3-4 as o/p.

Please help me with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a graph theory problem. Please provide sample input using `dput` (or Python equivalent) and expected sample output. See [ask] and [mcve]. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial.html):

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()    
>>> G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4])   
>>> G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)])
>>> nx.algorithms.shortest_path(G, 1, 4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.I need to pass the values dynamically.